# Sending sequence of bytes over MPI without concerns for datatype

Tags: mpi

I am working on an extension to a complex task-scheduling system built in C++. I need to be able to send a continuous sequence of bytes (where I have the starting memory address and the length in bytes of the data) between nodes in a cluster.

The problem is, I do not know the datatype of the object that needs to be sent. In fact, I don't think I care as I am just sending what is in the memory addresses across nodes (both of which know in advance what the type is).

So my question is: is there an MPI_NULL datatype, or is a datatype declaration arbitrary in this case? Any help is much appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are you looking for the `MPI_BYTE` predefined datatype ?  This seems so obvious that I suspect my answer is no answer at all ...

Comment: Well, let's just keep this quiet shall we! Thanks, don't know how I missed that.